# Url rewriting- Hide the folder structure

Tags: linux, apache, url-rewriting

Now my site url is somthing like this

http://mydomain.com/MainFolder/user/login.php

http://mydomain.com/MainFolder/reports/dashboard.php

I need to hide the folder structure from the URL.

So the url will look like

http://mydomain.com/login.php

http://mydomain.com/dashboard.php

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save that into `.htaccess` in your root web folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule login.php$ MainFolder/user/login.php
RewriteRule dashboard.php$ MainFolder/reports/dashboard.php
```

I don't know how many users you have - but this won't perform that good, because everytime someone accesses your site, the .htaccess file has to be read again. It would be better to include that in the vhost.conf (if possible!)...

Comment: I am confused with your answer.I do't have to use regular expressions for checking the mydomain.com?

Comment: Well - when you enter http://www.mydomain.com/login.php (assuming mydomain.com is **YOUR** domain), with my example of using Apaches `mod rewrite`, you will internally be redirected to `MainFolder/user/login.php`, because it is defined in the `.htaccess` file which is in YOUR web root folder (of mydomain.com).